# Arrays vs malloc?

Tags: c

If you want a dynamically allocated array of`int size`, there two ways you can get that in C:

```
int* array = new int [size]; //method 1
int* array2 = malloc (sizeof(int) * size); //method 2
```

When should you use each method?

Comment: Pick a language. This question is ridiculous with the current set of tags.

Comment: always use the second one .. why is this even a dilemma .. choose the second one and stick to it

Comment: Almost never use either.

Comment: 1) There is no such thing as "C/C++" (hence all the downvotes). 2) In C++, never use `malloc` unless you *have* to interface with ugly legacy C APIs.

Comment: Oh, and 3) in C++ never use `new` either. At the very worst you should use `make_unique/make_shared`.

Comment: Why should I use the second one instead of the first?

Comment: @dfg In C, always (this is the only way). In C++, only when you pass a bugger to a C API that `free`s said buffer.

Comment: Oops. I could edit my previous message but the (unintentional) misspelling totally reflects my inner thoughts, so let's keep it like this. xD **/gg/ff/** of course.

Comment: @sukhvir Why should I use the second one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another option, if the array will not be that big is to allocate it on the stack as a [VLA](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variable-length_array):

```
int array[size];
```

This will automatically free the memory when the variable leaves the scope, which may or may not be what you want. If you intend to use the variable outside the function it's allocated in, use the `malloc` way.

Answer (score 3):

If you're in C, the second one.

If you're in C++, use `std::vector<int>` if you can; otherwise use the first one (rarely needed).

Comment: Could you elaborate some more?

Comment: Before using `new`, one should consider smart pointers (`make_unique/shared`). Only when they fail (do they ever???) one should consider managing memory manually. But of course even before smart pointers, standard containers cover most of the cases.

Comment: Why should I use the second one in C?

Comment: Because the first isn't legal in C?

Comment: @dfg: Because `new` doesn't exist in C++.  You are melding two completely different languages.

Comment: @dfg: Same reason why you shouldn't say `new` in French. You should say `nouveau` instead.

Answer (score 0):

Another option (especially when memory needs to be zeroed):

```
int *array3 = calloc(size, sizeof array3[0]);
```

This protects against overflows (which must be checked in `size * sizeof array[0]` manually).